# How to convert existing UTC string to local timezone string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a string:

```
var utc_datetime = "02/09/2018 1:27 a.m."
```

I need it to show up in the user's local time. The format will always be the same, and it will always be queried in UTC timezone.

How can I accomplish this? I tried moment, and moment-timezone, but no luck so far.

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question. If you feel the answer given could be improved, edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dots and capitalize the AM or PM: Append 'UTC' to the string then convert it to a date

```js
var utc_datetime = "02/09/2018 1:27 a.m."
var new_datestring = utc_datetime.replace(/\./g,'').toUpperCase() + ' UTC';
var date = new Date(new_datestring);
var local_datetime = date.toString();
console.log(local_datetime)
```

Comment: `new_datestring = utc_datetime + ' UTC'`   

`var date = new Date(new_datestring)`   

winds up spitting out "Invalid Date"

Comment: This just needed one very small tweak because the a.m. needed to be AM :) I'll add the solution in the problem